# acount total number of letter ONLY alphabet

Tags: python-3.x

I have a txt about a English story. My work is counting the total number of letters in this story(alphabet only from "a" to "z" and "A"to "Z" ) . this is what I have wrote:

```
def count():
file=open("xxx.txt","r")
for line in file:
```

I dont know how to type next, cuz I only need letter but not 'space"，not"!",how can I improve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy way is to just count them all, then add up the ones you care about (`ascii_letters` in this case)

```
from collections import Counter
from string import ascii_letters

def count():
    c = Counter()
    with open("xxx.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            c.update(line)

    return sum(v for k, v in c.items() if k in ascii_letters)
```

Another terse approach is to use regex

```
def count():
    with open("xxx.txt","r") as file:
        return len(re.findall('[a-zA-Z]', file.read()))
```

Apparently this is homework and the teacher has imposed some arbitrary restrictions. Still not really any point using `ord` or `chr` here

```
def count():
    c = 0
    with open("xxx.txt","r") as file:
        for line in file:
            for ch in line:
                if 'a' <= ch <= 'z' or 'A' <= ch <= 'Z':
                    c += 1
    return c
```

Comment: thanks for your help,but i cant use it, my teacher allowed use "if" and give us a hint, using chr() and ord() to choose the characters line by line. i know you methods is batter but that is my assignment asked.